# Automatically restore windows as monitors are connected and disconnected?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, window-manager

I'm looking for a Windows 7 equivalent to the Mac OS utility [Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/) that let's you "automatically restore windows as displays are connected and disconnected".

I have a laptop that usually stays connected to two external monitors. When I undock the laptop all windows move onto the laptop's screen. When I later dock the laptop, I'd like each window to move back onto the monitor it came from. Of course the position and size should also be restored.

Comment: "Restore windows" = bring minimized windows to front or start new programs or move windows around to their previous positions?

Comment: Added a paragraph explaining "restore".